# eliminating 0s from objects in a vector which contain 0s

Tags: r

I have a vector of objects

```
A<-c(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,ll,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,x,y,z,aa,bb,cc,dd,ee)
```

All vector elements are 0 except the first (a)

```
A
[1] "s2" "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"    
"0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"
```

I would like to eliminate all 0s in the expression without indicating the possition and then eliminating, more an expression like

```
A<-names(which(A!=0))
A
NULL
```

However I get the error above. Would you happen to know how could I eliminate the zeros and obtain as a result of A "s2"

Comment: Not clear to me what you want. `A[A != "0"]`?

Comment: I would like to obtain A having eliminated al 0s your answer is correct. I was missing putting " in zero in the same expression, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that

```
A[which (A != 0)]
```

would work

Comment: `which` is redundant here. See the comment above by @blue-magister.